# How can I query the attribute of a rule in Bazel?

Tags: bazel, bazel-query

If I have

```
cc_binary(
    name = "stooges",
    srcs = [ "larry.cc", "curly.cc", "moe.cc" ],
)
```

Is there a Bazel query which will return `"larry.cc", "curly.cc", "moe.cc"` ?

At the moment the only thing I can think of is

```
$ bazel query --output=build //:stooges | perl -nwle 'print $1 if /srcs\s*=\s*\[([^]]*)\]/'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all labels listed in the `srcs` attribute:

```
bazel query 'labels(srcs,//your_package:your_target)'
```

In your case `bazel query 'labels(srcs,//:stooges)'`.

Should return:

```
//:larry.cc 
//:curly.cc
//:moe.cc
```

If you want to have all `hdrs` and `srcs` labels:

```
bazel query 'labels(srcs,//your_package:your_target) union labels(hdrs,//your_package:your_target)'
```

You can also make use of Bazel Aspects to query for source files. More details [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/aspects.html).